# behaupteter Urheber automatisch generierter Review-Kommentare

Tags: feature-request

Kürzlich habe ich dafür gestimmt, ein als Antwort klassifiziertes Posting zu löschen, weil es in Wahrheit keine Antwort ist, sondern ein Kommentar zu einer anderen Antwort.

Unter der entsprechenden "Antwort" wurde, ohne mich explizit darüber zu informieren, vom System folgender Kommentar eingefügt:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. – From Review – Hubert Schölnast

Siehe: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/46231/1487

Es steht dort zwar *» – From Review – «*, aber dort steht auch *»Hubert Schölnast«*. Leider steht mein Name aber exakt dort, wo er auch stehen würde, wenn ich diesen Kommentar geschrieben hätte.

Der Poster der reklamierten "Antwort" hat daher – wie ich finde aus durchaus nachvollziehbaren Gründen – nicht erkannt, dass dieser Kommentar automatisch generiert wurde. Er hat sich dann bei mir – von seinem Standpunkt aus übrigens ganz zurecht – gegen die vermeintlich von mir erhobene Anschuldigung gewehrt, er habe eine Antwort verfasst, die eine Klarstellung des Fragestellers erfordern würde.

Mich stört schon seit Längerem, dass mein Name bei ähnlichen automatisch generierten Kommentaren (z.B. Duplikat-Meldung) genau an der Stelle eingefügt wird, an der sonst der Autor des Kommentars steht. Denn dadurch entsteht der falsche Eindruck, der Initiator des Prozesses, der zur Erzeugung des Kommentars führt, wäre der Verfasser des Kommentars.

**Mein Vorschlag:**
Es soll bitte entweder der Name des Initiators des Prozesses ganz weggelassen werden, oder es soll **hinter** seinem Namen noch der Vermerk *"automatic generated message"* (oder etwas ähnliches) eingefügt werden, so dass jeder klar erkennen kann, dass der, dessen Name dort steht, zwar einen Prozess angestoßen hat, der zur Erzeugung der Meldung geführt hat, dass diese Person die Meldung aber nicht selbst formuliert hat.
Auf keinen Fall darf aber der Name des Initiators dort stehen, wo in "normalen" Kommentaren der Name des Verfassers steht, wenn der Initiator nicht der ist, der den Text formuliert hat.

Comment: Partly related: [Add indication that canned comments are from review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271829/4064062)

Answer (score 4):

> Unter der entsprechenden "Antwort" wurde, ohne mich explizit darüber zu informieren

Das stimmt nicht. Der Dialog, aus dem Du diesen Kommentar ausgewählt hast, beginnt mit:

> #### Add a comment for the author?
>
> Leaving a comment is optional, but can help the author learn how to improve their post or avoid making the same mistake in the future.

---

> Er hat sich dann bei mir – von seinem Standpunkt aus übrigens ganz zurecht – gegen die vermeintlich von mir erhobene Anschuldigung gewehrt, er habe eine Antwort verfasst, die eine Klarstellung des Fragestellers erfordern würde.

Mal als allgemeine Klarstellung: Die vorgefertigten Kommentare sind **nur** Kommentare – sonst nichts. Sie dienen dazu, dem Antwortschreiber eine Erklärung zu geben, was mit seiner Antwort problematisch ist. Als Sekundärfunktion teilen sie anderen Reviewern und Moderatoren mit, weswegen Du die Antwort als löschenswert erachtest. **Mehr nicht.** Wenn Du denkst, dass keiner der vorgefertigten Kommentare zur Situation passt, dann nutze auch keinen. Schreibe stattdessen einen regulären Kommentar oder passe einen vorgefertigten Kommentar an (Du kannst die automatisch generierten Kommentare ganz normal editieren). Du kannst auch gerne immer selbstgeschriebene Kommentare hinterlassen, wenn es Dir beliebt.

Noch eine allgemeine Anmerkung: Der Kommentar-als-Antwort-Kommentar¹ ist so gut wie nie passend². Falls tatsächlich mal jemand ohne Kommentarrechte eine Antwort schreibt, die ein guter Kommentar wäre (sprich: regt Verbesserung eines anderen Posts an, gibt eine relevante Referenz an, ein guter Witz, usw.), ist es zielführender, die Antwort für einen Moderator zu flaggen, dass sie in einen Kommentar konvertiert wird.

---

<sup>¹ »This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.«

² Wenn man mich fragt, wäre es besser, wenn es ihn gar nicht gäbe.</sup>